# Why Cast Entity Before convert List in EF 4.0?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

which one do you prefer? also which one has more securities and performance? BEST REGARDS..

```
    void FillGv()
        {
            using (Repository.DataRepository<Addresses_Temp> repo = new Repository.DataRepository<Addresses_Temp>(new Entities()))
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = repo.GetAll().ToList<Addresses_Temp>();
            }
        }
```

SECOND USAGE

```
    void FillGv()
        {
            using (Repository.DataRepository<Addresses_Temp> repo = new Repository.DataRepository<Addresses_Temp>(new Entities()))
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = repo.GetAll().ToList();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both do exactly the same thing. The second simply allows the call to ToList() to imply the generic type rather than defining it explicitly.

I prefer the second simply because it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Justin ... whats the point in casting it if there is no need?

The second one is a lot cleaner and clearer :-)